# Angular Use radio group in "ngFor"

Tags: angular, typescript

How is it possible to use "options" like radio in several questions?

Error whenever I set "ngModel" always select all.

follow code:

```
<div class="py-3" *ngFor="let pergunta of perguntas">  
            <label>{{pergunta.id}}</label> 
            <label>{{pergunta.texto_pergunta}}</label>   

                <div *ngFor="let opcao of ['Otimo','Bom','Regular','Ruim','Péssimo']">  
                    <input  class="form-check-input" type="radio"  
                            id="opcoes_{{pergunta.id}}" 
                            [ngModel]="pergunta.resposta" 
                            (ngModelChange) ="pergunta.resposta = $event" 
                            name="opcoes_{{pergunta.id}}"
                            value = "{{pergunta.id}}"
                            > 
                        {{opcao}}   
                </div> 
</div>
```

[Image herer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIMiR.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this radio button group you have configured it in a wrong manner. There are some rules that you need to follow when you are creating radio button groups.

1. For a single group `name` attribute should be same.
2. `value` attribute contains the value that you previewing as the label for that relevant radio button. (This is most of the time the same label value or a id of that value)

So in your case you have to change things in order to work your code properly.

```html
...
<input  class="form-check-input" type="radio"  
  id="opcoes_{{pergunta.id}}" 
  [ngModel]="pergunta.resposta" 
  (ngModelChange)="pergunta.resposta = $event" 
  name="opcoes_{{pergunta.id}}"
  value="{{opcao}}" 
> <!-- change value="{{pergunta.id}}" to value="{{opcao}}" -->
{{opcao}}
...
```

Comment: tks bro a lot..